# __dict__ does not work for numba jitclass object

Tags: python, class, numba

I'm trying to use `jitclass` from the `numba` module but when I'm trying to access to `myclass.__dict__` I get an error saying:

> {attributeerror} 'myclass' object has no attribute '__ dict __'.

Does there exist a solution to see what are the attributes in `myclass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#dir) to get all attributes of an object:

```
dir(myclass)
```

You can use [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#hasattr) to check if a certain attribute exists:

```
hasattr(myclass, "__dict__")
```

Comment: Ok, that's working with `dir(myclass)` but I need to add a line to remove the attributes starting with __. So `[m for m in dir(classdumodel) if not m[0] == '_']` works.